# Problems with CORDIC for Logarithm in C

Tags: c, numerical-methods, c99

In order to get started with CORDIC for `log10`, I implemented the algorithm derived in [this PDF, pp6](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/31117/cordic1.pdf):

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/31117/cordic1.pdf
float logf_cordic (float x, int B)
{
    float z = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 1; i <= B; i++)
    {
        if (x > 1.0f)
        {
            printf ("-");
            x = x - ldexpf (x, -i);
            z = z - log10f (1.0f - ldexpf (1.0f, -i));
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("+");
            x = x + ldexpf (x, -i);
            z = z - log10f (1.0f + ldexpf (1.0f, -i));
        }
    }
    return z;
}
```

This is a straight forward C99 implementation of the code from the paper, where I used [`ldexpf(x,n)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ldexpf) to compute x·2<sup>n</sup>. The paper claims that the method converges for `0.4194 < x < 3.4627`.  The program uses `1 ≤ x ≤ 2`.  The complete C99 code below prints:

```
+--+--+--+-+-+++--++ x = 1.00000: y = -0.000000, dy = -1.487272e-07
-+++++++++++++++++++ x = 1.12500: y = +0.099773, dy = +4.862081e-02
-+++++++++++++++++++ x = 1.25000: y = +0.099773, dy = +2.863325e-03
-+++-+--+-+--+-++--+ x = 1.37500: y = +0.138302, dy = -4.023314e-07
-++-+--++----+++--+- x = 1.50000: y = +0.176091, dy = -2.831221e-07
-+-+++++-++-++-++++- x = 1.62500: y = +0.210854, dy = +2.831221e-07
-+-+-+-+++++--+---++ x = 1.75000: y = +0.243038, dy = +2.235174e-07
-+--++-+--+---+---+- x = 1.87500: y = +0.273001, dy = +0.000000e+00
-+---+--+++--------- x = 2.00000: y = +0.301030, dy = -5.960464e-08
```

So it works as expected, except for `x = 1.125, 1.25` where the error is big and doesn't decrease when computing with more iterations.  I am now staring at that code for hours, but cannot find what I am missing...

---

- [Code in Compiler Explorer (gcc v11)](https://godbolt.org/z/c6P343jKz)

### Complete C99 code

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float logf_cordic (float x, int B)
{
    float z = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 1; i <= B; i++)
    {
        if (x > 1.0f)
        {
            printf ("-");
            x = x - ldexpf (x, -i);
            z = z - log10f (1.0f - ldexpf (1.0f, -i));
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("+");
            x = x + ldexpf (x, -i);
            z = z - log10f (1.0f + ldexpf (1.0f, -i));
        }
    }
    return z;
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ex = 3;
    int B = 20;

    if (argc >= 2)
        sscanf (argv[1], "%i", &ex);

    if (argc >= 3)
        sscanf (argv[2], "%i", &B);

    if (ex < 0) ex = 0;
    if (ex > 16) ex = 16;
    if (B > 100) B = 100;

    int n = 1 << ex;
    float dx = 1.0f / n;
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        float x = 1.0f + i * dx;
        float y = logf_cordic (x, B);
        float dy = y - log10f (x);
        printf (" x = %.5f: y = %+f, dy = %+e\n",
                (double) x, (double) y, (double) dy);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For reference, here is the algo as presented in the paper:

```
log10(x){
    z = 0;
    for ( i=1;i=<B;i++ ){
        if (x > 1)
            x = x - x*2^(-i);
            z = z - log10(1-2^(-i));
        else
            x = x + x*2^(-i);
            z = z - log10(1+2^(-i));
    }
return(z)
}
```

Comment: If you change `float` to `double` and increase step `ex`, you can see that all values below ≈`1.25826` are not accurate. Probably lower bound estimation `0.4194` is not correct. Note `0.4194 * 3 ≈ 1.25826`

Comment: IMO the algorithm itself is incorrect, because it assumes that `x` can be expanded as a product with factors 1±2^{-k}, which is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The algorithm is bogus.  The problem is that not all numbers can be presented in the form

x = Π (1 ± 2<sup>−k</sup>)

See this [discussion on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4767945/746312).
There doesn't even exist an interval [a,b] such that all x's in that interval can be represented in that form.

---

What *does exist* though is a representation of the form

x = Π (1 + a<sub>k</sub>·2<sup>−k</sup>)

with a<sub>k</sub> in { 0, 1 } for all 1 ≤ x ≤ 2.38 = x<sub>0</sub>, and this is enough to fix the algorithm:

To compute log<sub>B</sub>(x), first normalize the argument x such that
1 / x<sub>0</sub> ≤ x ≤ 1.

Then apply the following algorithm to the reduced x:

```
logB_cordic (x, N)
    z = 0
    xmax = 1 + 2^{−N−1}
    FOR k = 1 ... N
        xk = x + x·2^{-k}
        IF xk ≤ xmax
            x = xk;
            z = z - logB (1 + 2^{−k})
    return z
```

In practice, `N` is fixed and the N `logB` values come from a lookup-table. Apart from that, the method requires additions, comparisions, and shifts by variable offsets.

The comparison `IF xk ≤ xmax` makes the final absolute error (almost) symmetric around 0. With `IF xk ≤ 1` the absolute error would be asymmetric and twice as high.

### Results

For reference, below is an implementation in C99 that adds some confidence that the fixed algorithm is actually working. It's B = 2, N = 10, and the plot is for 16385 values of x evenly spaced over [0.5, 1].
 (click to enlarge)

[image: Absolute error of a C99 implementation with N=10]

**C99 Code**

```cpp
#include <math.h>

double log2_cordic (double x, int N)
{
    double xmax = 1.0 + ldexp (1.0, -N - 1);
    double z = 0.0;

    for (int k = 1; k <= N; k++)
    {
        double x_bk = x + ldexp (x, -k);

        if (x_bk <= xmax)
        {
            x = x_bk;
            z = z - log2 (1.0 + ldexp (1.0, -k));
        }
    }
    return z;
}
```

---

### Edit:

Just found out that I reinvented the wheel... According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Feynman%27s_algorithm), it's a method Feynman already used during the Manhattan Project.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a complete answer. The question simply catched my eye and I decided to take a dive and have some fun.

I've tested the algorithm as given in the paper in Python using floats and also converting to fixed point and my results are the same as yours. I've also found some other problematic points, such as `x = 1.60000`, `x = 2.00625`, `x = 2.03750` and `x = 2.06875`.

I'll use the following convention:

```
b_i+ = (1 + 2^-i)
b_i- = (1 - 2^-i)
```

The algorithm can thus be written:

```
log10(x) {
    z = 0;
    for (i = 1; i =< B; i++) {
        if (x > 1)
            x *= b_i-;
            z -= log10(b_i-);
        else
            x *= b_i+;
            z -= log10(b_i+);
    }
    return(z)
}
```

I'm not sure the claim that we can choose `b_i` of the form `(1 ± 2^-i)` is in itself wrong, but I've noticed that *the criteria for choosing each `b_i`* might be. For example, when `x == 1.125`, the sequence currently is

```
x *= b_1- == 0.562500, z -= log10(b_1-) == 0.301030
x *= b_2+ == 0.703125, z -= log10(b_2+) == 0.204120
x *= b_3+ == 0.791016, z -= log10(b_3+) == 0.152967
x *= b_4+ == 0.840454, z -= log10(b_4+) == 0.126639
x *= b_5+ == 0.866718, z -= log10(b_5+) == 0.113275
x *= b_6+ == 0.880261, z -= log10(b_6+) == 0.106541
x *= b_7+ == 0.887138, z -= log10(b_7+) == 0.103161
x *= b_8+ == 0.890603, z -= log10(b_8+) == 0.101468
                        ...
```

`x` never reaches `1` and the value of `z` is wrong. However, if we start with `b_1+` (instead of `b_1-`), the sequence is:

```
x *= b_1+ == 1.687500; z -= log10(b_1+) == -0.176091
x *= b_2- == 1.265625; z -= log10(b_2-) == -0.051152
x *= b_3- == 1.107421; z -= log10(b_3-) ==  0.006839
x *= b_4- == 1.038208; z -= log10(b_4-) ==  0.034868
x *= b_5- == 1.005764; z -= log10(b_5-) ==  0.048656
x *= b_6- == 0.990048; z -= log10(b_6+) ==  0.055495
x *= b_7+ == 0.997783; z -= log10(b_7+) ==  0.052116
x *= b_8+ == 1.001681; z -= log10(b_8-) ==  0.050422
                        ...
```

which converges to the correct result.

For `x == 2.00625`, right now the algorithm uses

```
b_1- b_2- b_3+ b_4+ b_5+ b_6+ b_7+ b_8+, ...
```

and `x` settles to about `x == 0.957`. But if we change to `b_2+` instead, the sequence is

```
b_1- b_2+ b_3- b_4- b_5- b_6+ b_7- b_8-
```

which makes `x == 1.0002` and `z == 0.323317` (correct again).

My intuition<sup>[1]</sup> is that we can always choose a series of `b_i`s of the form `(1 ± 2^-i)` that satisfies `x * b_1 * ... * b_B == 1`,<sup>[2]</sup> but using

```
b_i = 1 + 2^-i if x * b1 * b2 * ... * b_i-1 < 1
b_i = 1 - 2^-i if x * b1 * b2 * ... * b_i-1 > 1
```

is not the appropriate criteria for choosing. The condition `(x > 1.0)` should be replaced by a smarter one which has so far escaped me.

---

[1] It turned out my intuition was wrong (again!). See OP's answer.

[2] And so use lookup tables and simple shift-and-add operations to calculate the logarithms, which is the purpose of the algorithm.

Comment: I haven't been through the CORDIC logic, but you certainly get an A for effort and a well formatted and reasoned answer.

Comment: I found that not all numbers can be represented as (1 ± 2^-i), there are infintely many intervals missing.

Answer (score 1):

I would quibble with calling this CORDIC computation. CORDIC in hyperbolic vectoring mode can compute tanh<sup>-1</sup>, and that can be used to compute logarithms with a bit of pre-processing and post-processing. This logarithm computation is closely patterned on binary longhand division and the algorithm has therefore been referred to as pseudo-division. The general approach dates back to how Henry Briggs computed his tables of logarithms.

In binary division, various digit sets can be utilized, for example the digit set {0, 1} in the restoring or "non-performing" variant or {-1, 1} if one uses the non-restoring variant (I am using -1 here in lieu of a 1 with overline). It seems the author of the document linked in the question incorrectly assumed that the non-restoring division algorithm would translate directly into a corresponding pseudo-division for logarithms, using the digit set {-1, 1} to represent factors (1-2<sup>-i</sup>) and (1+2<sup>-i</sup>) during the multiplicative normalization process. However, as other answers have pointed out, this does not work as not all arguments can be normalized to unity in this way.

The simplest approach to compute logarithms by pseudo-division is to use the digit set {0, 1} in a "non-performing" algorithm as I demonstrated in my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159300/compute-logarithmic-expression-without-floating-point-arithmetics-or-log). It is also possible to use the digit set {-1, 0, 1} corresponding to normalization factors (1+2<sup>-i</sup>), 1, (1-2<sup>-i</sup>), as De Lugish showed in his Ph.D. thesis. He designed shared hardware for the bit-wise computation of multiplications, divisions, square root, and various transcendental functions:

Bruce Gene De Lugish, *A class of Algorithms for Automatic Evaluation of Certain Elementary Functions in a Binary Computer*, Report No. 399, Department of Computer Science, University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign, June 1970.

Below is an ISO-C99 implementation of `log()` based directly on the description in this report. Since I had been aware of De Lugish's work but never utilized it until now, I wrote the code for clarity of exposition for my own benefit rather than attempting to maximize performance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// ln(1+2*(-i))
float tabp [24];
// ln(1-2*(-i))
float tabm [24];

float logf_delugish (float a)
{
    const float three_eigth = 0.375f;
    const float ln2 = 0.69314718056f;
    int sk, expo;
    float sum = tabm[0], x = frexpf (a, &expo), ex2 = 1.0f;
    x = 2.0f * x;
    for (int k = 0; k < 24; k++) {
        sk = 0;
        if ((x - 1.0f) <  (-three_eigth * ex2)) sk = +1;
        if ((x - 1.0f) >= (+three_eigth * ex2)) sk = -1;
        ex2 *= 0.5f;
        if (sk == 1) {
            x = x + x * ex2;
            sum = sum - tabp [k];
        } 
        if (sk == -1) {
            x = x - x * ex2;
            sum = sum - tabm [k];
        }
    }
    return expo * ln2 + sum;
}

float tabp [24] =
{ 
    0.40546510810816f,
    0.22314355131421f,
    0.11778303565638f,
    0.06062462181643f,
    0.03077165866675f,
    0.01550418653597f,
    0.00778214044205f,
    0.00389864041566f,
    0.00195122013126f,
    0.00097608597306f,
    0.00048816207950f,
    0.00024411082753f,
    0.00012206286253f,
    0.00006103329368f,
    0.00003051711247f,
    0.00001525867265f,
    0.00000762936543f,
    0.00000381468999f,
    0.00000190734681f,
    0.00000095367386f,
    0.00000047683704f,
    0.00000023841855f,
    0.00000011920928f,
    0.00000005960464f,
};

// ln(1-2*(-i))
float tabm [24] =
{
    -0.69314718055995f,
    -0.28768207245178f,
    -0.13353139262452f,
    -0.06453852113757f,
    -0.03174869831458f,
    -0.01574835696814f,
    -0.00784317746103f,
    -0.00391389932114f,
    -0.00195503483580f,
    -0.00097703964783f,
    -0.00048840049811f,
    -0.00024417043217f,
    -0.00012207776369f,
    -0.00006103701897f,
    -0.00003051804380f,
    -0.00001525890548f,
    -0.00000762942364f,
    -0.00000381470454f,
    -0.00000190735045f,
    -0.00000095367477f,
    -0.00000047683727f,
    -0.00000023841861f,
    -0.00000011920930f,
    -0.00000005960465f,
};

#define LIMIT (256)

int main (void)
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    float sumerrsq = 0;
    float maxerr = 0, maxerr_loc = INFINITY;
    float a = 1.0f / LIMIT;
    do {
        float res = logf_delugish (a);
        double ref = log ((double)a);
        float err = fabsf (res - ref);
        sumerrsq += err * err;
        if (err > maxerr) {
            maxerr = err;
            maxerr_loc = a;
        }
        a = nextafterf (a, INFINITY);
        count++;
    } while (a < LIMIT);
    printf ("maxerr = %15.8e @ %15.8e  RMS err = %15.8e\n", 
            maxerr, maxerr_loc, sqrt(sumerrsq / count));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What's the advantage? Faster convergence than with what I cane up with in the other answer? Cuurently, the bottleneck is that I am on a 8-bit controller without barrel shifter; and in either algorithm that's consuming the most execution time by far.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts The "non-performing" variants are typically the way to go for software implementation. Other variants like the one by de Lugish can speed up hardware implementation (using parallelism, redundant encodings). If you follow the link in my answer you can see `log2()` code I provided for an asker using a 16-bit controller IIRC. When I did embedded work years ago I used fixed-point computation based on tables and interpolation (requires multiplication) for `log()` and `exp()`. Might that be suitable in your context? How much memory can be dedicated to this functionality?

Comment: I saw that other code with the unrolled loop, but loop unrolling that much would cost too much program memory, and the speed gain is not a game changer. I'd like to use not too much memory, because it would be in the context of a Lib, i.e. I am not the end user.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts You do *not* have to unroll the loops as I did. It does help with slow shifts though, as fixed-size shifts can easily be broken down into combinations byte-moves and single-bit shifts (as we did in the days of 8086 CPUs in the early 1980s). How much accuracy do you need? For a fast, very low accuracy approach maybe try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75808036/780717). For approaches using tables and polynomials look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54663860/780717).